# How do I testfor a certain item in my offhand in minecraft 1.12?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to test if a player with a score of 500 has a nether star in their offhand. The objective I am using is a dummy called Sanguinare. I get the response, Player does not have the required data structure with the command:

```
/testfor @p[score_Sanguinare_min=500]
{Inventory:[{Slot:-106b,id:"minecraft:nether_star",count:1b}]}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have a nether star in my offhand and a score of 500. I'm doing everything on a single player world.

Comment: "Sanguinare"? Will you also know what that scoreboard is for if you come back to the map in 3 years?

Comment: its named Sanguinare because im making a vampire module. and i am aware that sanguinare means blood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `Count` instead of `count`.